# Sql Server query performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, performance

I have contacts that can be in more than one group and have more than one request. I need to simply get contacts for a specific group that have no specific requests.

How do I improve the performance of this query:

```
SELECT  top 1 con_name ,
        con_id
FROM    tbl_group_to_contact gc
        INNER JOIN tbl_contact c ON gc.con_id = c.id
WHERE   group_id = '81'
        AND NOT c.id IN ( SELECT    con_id
                          FROM      tbl_request_to_contact
                          WHERE     request_id = '124' )
```

When I run that query with Explanation plan it shows that this query:

```
SELECT    con_id
                          FROM      tbl_request_to_contact
                          WHERE     request_id = '124'
```

is expensive with using an index seek.

```
 |--Top(TOP EXPRESSION:((1)))
       |--Nested Loops(Left Anti Semi Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([c].[id]))
            |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([gc].[con_id], [Expr1006]) WITH UNORDERED PREFETCH)
            |    |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([db_newsletter].[dbo].[tbl_group_to_contact].[PK_tbl_group_to_contact_1] AS [gc]),  WHERE:([db_newsletter].[dbo].[tbl_group_to_contact].[group_id] as [gc].[group_id]=(81)) ORDERED FORWARD)
            |    |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([db_newsletter].[dbo].[tbl_contact].[PK_tbl_contact] AS [c]), SEEK:([c].[id]=[db_newsletter].[dbo].[tbl_group_to_contact].[con_id] as [gc].[con_id]) ORDERED FORWARD)
            |--Top(TOP EXPRESSION:((1)))
                 |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([db_newsletter].[dbo].[tbl_request_to_contact].[PK_tbl_request_to_contact] AS [cc]), SEEK:([cc].[request_id]=(124)),  WHERE:([db_newsletter].[dbo].[tbl_contact].[id] as [c].[id]=[db_newsletter].[dbo].[tbl_request_to_contact].[con_id] as [cc].[con_id]) ORDERED FORWARD)
```

Comment: Can't do it off-the-cuff, but you may find you can remove the subselect and use an outer join on `tbl_request_to_contact` combined with a `GROUP BY` clause and the `HAVING` qualifier (e.g., `HAVING COUNT(request_id) = 0`) may help.

Comment: In `SQL Server`, `LEFT JOIN` performs worse than `IN`, to say nothing of the `GROUP BY / HAVING` (which can be easily replaced by mere `IS NULL` in the `WHERE` clause).

Comment: What is the request_id = '124' for?  Other request id's don't matter?

Comment: Could you please post the complete execution plan? Just run `SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON \n GO \n SELECT …`

Comment: @Quassnoi: You're quite right, in this case if you used `GROUP BY`, the `HAVING COUNT(request_id) = 0` would be better expressed with `WHERE request_id IS NULL` in the `WHERE` clause. Interesting about SQL Server and `LEFT JOIN` vs subselects, do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @TJCrowder: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Comment: @msony: you don't have an index on `group_to_contact`. Create one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is ok, just create the following indexes:

```
tbl_request_to_contact (request_id, con_id)
tbl_group_to_contact (group_id, con_id)
```

Since the tables seem to be the link tables, you want to make these composites the primary keys:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_request_to_contact ADD CONSTRAINT pk_rc PRIMARY KEY (request_id, con_id)
ALTER TABLE tbl_group_to_contact ADD CONSTRAINT pk_gc (group_id, con_id)
```

, making sure that `request_id` and `group_id` go first.

Also, if your `request_id` and `group_id` are integers, pass the integers as the parameters, not strings:

```
SELECT  con_name, con_id
FROM    tbl_group_to_contact gc
JOIN    tbl_contact c
ON      c.id = gc.con_id
WHERE   group_id = 81
        AND c.id NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  con_id
        FROM    tbl_request_to_contact
        WHERE   request_id = 124
        )
```

, or an implicit conversion may occur rendering the indexes unusable.

**Update:**

From your plan I see that you miss the index on `tbl_group_to_contact`. Full table scan is required to filter the groups.

Create the index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux_gc ON tbl_group_to_contact (group_id, con_id)
```

Comment: Agree on the first index. Care to explain on the second? Would add INCLUDE (con_name)

Comment: you know what? i deleted top 1 from select statement and it started work much faster, how can u explain it? my i use another approach for selecting only one row?

Comment: @Frank: the second just helps to filter the groups. `con_name` most probably belongs to `tbl_contact`, not `tbl_group_to_contact`.

Comment: True, who knows with a doubt from the given query. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try running the [SQL Server Database Tuning Advisor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166575.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Quassnoi with the indexes.  Plus you can use a left join to only show users who don't have requests.  This usually has better performance than a sub-query.

What is the request_id = '124' for?  Other request id's don't matter?

```
SELECT  con_name ,
        con_id
FROM    tbl_group_to_contact gc
        INNER JOIN tbl_contact c ON gc.con_id = c.id
        LEFT JOIN tbl_request_to_contact rtc ON gc.con_id = rtc.con_id
WHERE   group_id = '81' and rtc.request_id IS NULL
```

Comment: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Comment: i cannot use request_id IS NULL, i need specific request_id

Comment: @Quassnoi: regarding your article... is there any way to contact you for a question or two?

Comment: @msony: `request_id IS NULL` applied to the `LEFT JOIN` does the same as the `NOT IN` you originally used. However, in `SQL Server`, `NOT IN` behaves same or better than `LEFT JOIN`, so there is no point in rewriting the query.

Comment: Quassnoi, now that's pretty interesting.

Comment: @msony, why do you need a specific value?    
I guess all of this is mute if you go with the not in suggested by Quassnoi